# TFS build fails when running custom powershell script

Tags: powershell

I've added a Powershell script step to my on-premises TFS 2015 build definition. The script modifies assembly version in AssemblyInfo.cs file.

I tested the script with the Build Agent account in PowerShell ISE and it worked fine. However, the PowerShell step fails in TFS build with an access denied error.

The Build Agent account has full control permission to `C:\agent\_work\11\s\source\MyProject\Properties` folder.

> Get-Content : Access to the path 'C:\agent_work\11\s\source\MyProject\Properties' is denied.
>   At C:\agent_work\11\s\source\MyProject\BuildScript\Update-AssembyInfoFile.ps1:64 char:10
>   + (Get-Content $file) |
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied: (C:\agent_work...MyProject\Properties:String) [Get-Content], Unauthorized 
>   AccessException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: What kind of the build service account you use, a local account or a domain account or the system account? Please change the build agent server account to another account which is the computer administrator and try again. If still not work, try the to use "Network Service" account to run.

Comment: Maybe you could try to install [Manifest Versioning Build Tasks extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-Versioning-Task&serverKey=null) and use the step "Version .NET Assemblies" step to set the version in the assemblyinfo.cs file in build.

Comment: The TFS build server is run under domain Build Agent account that is a member of local Administrator group in our TFS Windows 2012 server . Also, the Build Agent account is a member of domain administrators group. I added additional code to my script to show the domain and user name running the script. The output confirmed the script is run by Build Agent account as expected. When I logon to TFS build server using

Comment: When I logon to TFS build server using Build Agent account I can read the 'C:\agent_work\11\s\source\MyProject\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs file without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The script error was caused by missing the file name in the file path. The message *Access to the path 'C:\agent_work\11\s\source\MyProject\Properties' is denied* is kind of confusing but it gives you idea that the file name is missing in the path. The path in the error message is a folder name rather than a filename. Hence, the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Please mark the reply as the answer.